# Tiff image created with php Imagick is incorrectly displayed in Imagej

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, tiff, imagej

I calculate the average image of a set of 16 bit unsigned *.tiff* images, and save it with Imagick:

```
// Image averaging 
$img_aux = new Imagick(); 
$num_rows = 0;
while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    $num_rows++;
    $file = $row['File'];
    if ($num_rows == 1) {
        $img_avg = new Imagick();
        if (!$img_avg->readImage($file))    throw new Exception("Problem averaging the images");
    }
    else {
        if (!$img_aux->readImage($file))    throw new Exception("Problem averaging the images");
        $opacity = 1.0 / (1.0 * $num_rows); 
        $img_aux->setImageOpacity($opacity);
        $img_avg->setImageOpacity(1 - $opacity);                    
        $img_avg->compositeImage($img_aux, imagick::COMPOSITE_PLUS, 0, 0); 
    };
};

// Save image
$save_file = tempnam($globals['path_img'], ''); 
$img_avg->setImageFormat("tiff");
$img_avg->setImageDepth(16); 
if (!$img_avg->writeImage($save_file))    throw new Exception("Problem averaging the images"); 
$img_avg->destroy();
```

The image that I get back is correctly opened and displayed in several viewers but not in Imagej. Imagej identifies the new image as 32 bit RGB.

Why? How can I solve this?

**Examples:**

A 16 bit tiff image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1971mez6478ktqp/test.tif

The average of two times the image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/di1e9x4y9007r6y/average.tif

Comment: Have you tried using Bio-Formats, as suggested by @ctrueden? It would be helpful if you provide an example image.

Comment: @JanEglinger I must use Imagej without the Bio-Formats plugin. You can download examples now.

Comment: I can only second ctrueden's suggestion to post to the ImageJ mailing list (including the sample images) to get the bug fixed. Bio-Formats is opening both files correctly by the way. The difference when opening with ImageJ directly seems to be in the TIFF-Tag 258 ("BitsPerSample"), where I get _value=218, count=3_ for test.tif and _value=5898510, count=4_ for average.tif when the debug mode is active.

Comment: Wayne Rasband is very unlikely to see this question on Stack Overflow, and he retains sole control over the ImageJ1 codebase. So the *only* way to get this bug fixed in ImageJ1 core is to post to the ImageJ mailing list. That said, the ImageJ 2.0.0 release (due by June 1) will unify the behavior of File > Open to use the [SCIFIO](http://scif.io/) library first, which uses essentially the same code as Bio-Formats to open TIFFs. So this problem will be solved relatively soon.

Comment: Also, I am very curious why you "must use Imagej without the Bio-Formats plugin." Is this mandated by your institution? If so, why?

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely a bug in ImageJ. If you want it fixed, your best bet is to make the non-working `.tiff` file available online, then write to the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.net/list.html) for assistance.

You could also try reading in the `.tiff` file using the [Bio-Formats](http://fiji.sc/Bio-Formats) Importer plugin, bundled with the [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/) distribution of ImageJ.